# Why multiple 'Free Space' blocks when looking at disks utility

Tags: disk, disk-usage, disk-management

Here's a picture of what I see when looking at disks utility:
[image]

Why do I have 2 Free Space blocks?

Can I combine them into one? If so how? Are these 'blocks' called partitions?

Comment: They are not partitions as not formatted. You would have to move 4 left to put unallocated next to each other to make one larger partition with gparted from live installer. That can take a while even with a fast NVMe drive as it has to copy all data and any interruption corrupts the data. Or good backups required. Since gpt, you can make partitions in each unallocated. With SSD having some unallocated/unused is suggested. I keep some for future use as I do not know if I want more data storage or another test install to experiment with changes that I do not want to change working install.

Comment: Would be easier to add them to each Ubuntu partition to the left, instead of trying to move partitions/free space around.  Or just leave them be till you need more space on a partition, they not hurting anything.

Comment: @crip659 how would I do that though? Just by increasing the size of the existing partitions?

Comment: Use gparted in a Live Ubuntu USB, and should just need to expand.  They are in best place to make your Ubuntu partitions bigger, if needed.  56GBs for partition 3, 150 for partition 4.  If don't need to expand would leave as is for now.  Bigger partitions not always needed, unless partition is passing 70% full or more.